# How do you create a report with every URL hit between two date/time's in an Azure web app?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have an Azure web app with Application insights.
I need a report that shows every URL hit, when, and if possible, how long it took to execute.
In Pseudo code, something like this

```
select URL, Date, Duration from WebSite where Date between '1 April 2022 08:00:00' and '2 April 2022 08:00:00'
```

Results would look like this:

/page1   '1 April 2022 08:01:23'    203ms

/page3   '1 April 2022 08:02:03'    103ms

/page2   '1 April 2022 08:02:04'    83ms

/page5   '1 April 2022 08:03:08'    93ms

Is this possible? If so, what is the query?

Comment: Sure, it is a simple query when using kusto, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/. You can write kusto queries using the Logs page, see https://azure.github.io/Industrial-IoT/tutorials/tut-applicationinsights.html#:~:text=on%20Azure%20portal.-,View%20logs%20in%20Application%20Insights,Time%20Range%20and%20click%20Run.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend getting this report directly from the app service HTTP logs because data in Application Insights can be sampled depending on how it is configured for your infrastructure.

In order to get the report from app service logs, go to the app service and select "Logs" in the left-hand side menu. Then use the following query:

```
AppServiceHTTPLogs 
| where TimeGenerated between (datetime(2022-04-01T00:00:00Z) .. 1d)
| project CsUriStem, TimeGenerated, TimeTaken
```

You can specify the date range directly in the query or select it in the "Time range" dropdown:
[image: time range dropdown]

If you want to run a similar report by using Application Insights data, the query will look like this:

```
requests
| where cloud_RoleName == 'your app service role name'
| where timestamp  between (datetime(2022-04-01T00:00:00Z) .. 1d)
| project url, timestamp, duration
```

Please note that you may need to filter by `cloud_RoleName` or `cloud_RoleInstance` if multiple app services are connected to the same Application Insights resource.